# How does @media queries work?

Tags: android, css, video, youtube, embed

I am trying to make a responsive embeded youtube video and I don't understand how @media queries work, well for me they don't work..

First of all I tried to make it smaller on tablets, but it has no effect :/

The code I use:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:768px) {
    .video {width: 40% !important; }
    .vid {position: absolute; top: 20%;}
}
```

I want the video to become smaller to fit to the left of the title and under "Last Update:"

Images:
(it did not work)
[http://m.imgur.com/3ydAlCv](https://m.imgur.com/3ydAlCv)
[http://m.imgur.com/AdOmoEv](https://m.imgur.com/AdOmoEv)

Also on phones I'd like to make the youtube video go under the title and center the title and the video but thats something harder.. I am not even able to make this little thing..

So I just want to resize the video on tablet so it will fit under "Last Update:" and to the left of the Title "Overworld Roleplay".

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Homepage | Overworld RP Devs</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/maintemplate.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">Overworld Roleplay</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="front container">

      <h1 class="text-primary" id="title" >Overworld Roleplay</h1>
      <h4>Development Website</h4>

    </div><!-- /.container -->

    <!-- <div class="videoWrapperOuter">
        <div class="videoWrapperInner">
            <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/C6-TWRn0k4I" 
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div> -->

    <div class="video container">   
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="vid">
                <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ac7KhViaVqc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div><!--./vid -->
            <h2 class="text-info" id="last" >Last Update:</h2>
        </div><!--.col -->
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/transition.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/tab.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/popover.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/npm.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/modal.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/carrousel.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/button.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/alert.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/affix.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.starter-template {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

html, body {
    background-color: black;
    background: url(/images/bg.jpg); 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*background-position: center;*/
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.front {
    position: absolute;
    left: 54%;
    top: 30%;
    width: 46%;
}

#title {
    font-size: 60px;
    word-wrap: normal;
}

.vid {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

.vid iframe,
.vid object,
.vid embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 27%;
    left: 3%;
    width: 77%;
    height: 68%;
    border: 0;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: white;
}

.navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color:black;
}

#last {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 15%;
}

.video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:768px) {
    .video {width: 40% !important; }
    .vid {position: absolute; top: 20%;}
}
```

Comment: did you place it after any original styles and have the overriding styles to the same specificity or higher?  Also, are you sure the device you are testing on is within those pixel ranges - there are some very high def mobile devices out there

Comment: Without your complete HTML and CSS, it's hard to answer. It is depends on other elements too.

Comment: I've added the CSS above @Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that your `.video` is an `<iframe>`, `<embed>` etc., try

```
.video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
}
```

and put it in a container (a div or section) with styles like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .video_container {
        width: 40%;
    }
}
```

So, on viewports with widths, for example, smaller than 767px the container will get 40% width relatively to its parent and your video inside will just adjust. You are getting the approach, I hope. And your question in the caption is somewhat broad indeed. Also as others have pointed out, attaching the code never hurts :)

Comment: I've added the HTML and CSS above.

Comment: remove  `.vid iframe, .vid object, .vid embed {...}` styles, add `iframe {max-width:100%; height:auto;}` and `.vid {width:100%;}`

Comment: The size worked but the pozition has no effect:
@media only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:768px) {
 .video {width: 40% !important; }
 **.vid {position: absolute; top: 40%;}**
}

it just sticks to the top

Comment: also there is a bloat in your code. You don't need 3 containers for you video. And what you are trying to achieve with `position: absolute; top: 40%;` is done by setting margins. Positioning is used wrongly (I mean, it is out of place here) too. Try to redo it in a cleaner way, maybe take as an example something from around the web. And learn in the first place native styles and markup, don't start with bootstrap.

Comment: I am trying to fix it now, one more thing, on phones, the video won't show up and I also want to hide the text "Last Update:" which is above it, and I tried this: #last {text-indent: 100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; } but it doesnt work, any idea why?
Also I am trying to change the height of it and I can't > http://imgur.com/a/hUKds, I tried  iframe {
    max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 height: auto;
 width: 60%;
 height: 60%;
}

Comment: add `position: absolute; top: 40%;` to `.video` instead of adding it to `.vid`. To hide elements use `your_selector {display:none;}`

Comment: and remove from `.vid` `padding-bottom: 56.25%; height:0;`

Comment: I can't change the size of it now :/ Trying  .video {
 position: absolute;
 width: 60%;
 height: 30%;
} and not working

Comment: you don't need height on .video - its height will be based on the content inside. I strongly recommend that you should start with something easier and exclude bootstrap -  now you are just doing it wrong in all the possible ways :)

Comment: I am using bootstrap here but I dont really understand it right now..
I did height on the iframe{ and it worked, and I also did margins on the vid so I can position it, check it out on http://zgaming.comxa.com it works well so far :?

Comment: well, in this case you have to read about it before using, if your goal is to learn something and be able to build sites properly. There is no other way. So, take your time to learn all the stuff out there.

Comment: Add #last {display: none;} to your media query at the size you want the text to disappear.

`@media only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:768px) {
    #last {display: none;}
    .video {width: 40% !important; }
    .vid {position: absolute; top: 20%;}
}`